# Lotusscript Sorting String Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to sort a string Array which is a result of two Array lists (Added and Changed Dates).

```
combinedAddChangeDates = FullTrim(ArrayAppend(ChangeDate,addDate))

vResult = Evaluate (|@Sort(combinedAddChangeDates)|)
```

I'm getting nothing as vResult. Can you please help me?

The value of combinedAddChangeDates are as follow:

- [1] "22/04/2022-01:00 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"
- [2] "23/04/2022-01:15 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"
- [3] "06/04/2022-08:00 AM-06:00 PM-Added"

I want to sort them according to their string date:

- [1] "06/04/2022-08:00 AM-06:00 PM-Added"
- [2] "22/04/2022-01:00 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"
- [3] "23/04/2022-01:15 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"

Is this possible in Lotusscript? Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to extract the dates and convert them to datetime. Otherwise it will sort as a string, and that means 06/04 will be before 07/03 ...

Answer (score 1):

The `Evaluate` function doesn't recognise LotusScript variables, so when you do `Evaluate(|@Sort(combinedAddChangeDates)|)`, it sees `combinedAddChangeDates` as an undefined variable with the default value of an empty string.

To use a LotusScript variable in `Evaluate`, you have to convert the variable to a string and append it to the formula with delimiters so that the formula sees it as a literal value.

Furthermore in the case of an array, you have to represent the array as a literal formula-language list, with elements separated by colons. The following should work:

`vResult = Evaluate(|@Sort("| + Join(combinedAddChangeDates, |":"|) + |")|)`

An alternative is to implement a pure LotusScript sorting function, so you don't call `Evaluate` at all. There may be examples of this elsewhere on the internet.

This solution just sorts the array elements as strings, and ignores the fact that your data contains dates. Sorting based on dates is much more complicated when you have string data: you'd need to extract the date part from each element, convert that to an actual date/time data type (e.g. with the LotusScript `CDat` function), build and sort a new array from the date/time data, then join the sorted dates back to the text parts ("-Added" or "-Changed") if you still need those parts.

I haven't provided code for the date-sorting, because that will take longer than I have time for.

Comment: Hello @ScottLeis, I tried your solution but if I chose a different month, it's returning me this:

`[1] "03/05/2022-08:00 AM-06:00 PM-Added"`

`[2] "22/04/2022-01:00 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"`

`[3] "23/04/2022-01:15 PM-06:00 PM-Changed"`

The day is sorted out but not the month part.

Comment: @Ragome - I've added a paragraph as a rough guide for sorting the dates properly. That's all I can do currently.

Comment: Just another alternative: you can use Java from LotusScript, see LS2J in the Designer Help database. Java offers extensive sorting features that should make it possible to sort a string array with a specific format based on the dates, provided that you add a comparison function yourself.

Comment: Here is one example of a LotusScript sort routine. 

http://domquery.info/samples/sandbox.nsf/ByApplicationName/86cf1eb52622488f85256d51004eeb72?OpenDocument

Comment: And here's another one, implemented as a class. https://gist.github.com/Lokutus/3018969  Note that I can't vouch for either of them. I'm sure I wrote one myself around 20 years ago, and if I could find it I'd post it, but these came up with a simple Google search.